# Replace straight quotation marks with typographic ones: "My text" to „My text“

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to change "My text" to „My text“ everywhere automatically, because this is the correct way this is written in German. The quotation marks can be anywhere in the text.

**Is there an easy way to achieve this?**

The solution should check the very first character, the very last, something like "this", or (check "this") ...

My current approach is:

```
public static string FixGermanQuotationMarks(string input)
{
    string output = input;
    if (output[0] == '"') output = "„" + output.Substring(1, output.Length - 1);

    if (output.EndsWith("\"")) output = output.Substring(0, output.Length-1) + '“';

    output = output
        .Replace(" \"", " „")
        .Replace("(\"", "(„")
        .Replace("<\"", "<„")

        .Replace("\".", "“.")
        .Replace("\")", "“)")
        .Replace("\"<", "“<")
        .Replace("\" ", "“ ");

    return output;
}
```

but this is not elegant at all.

EDIT:

I was asked for example input and output. Here you go:

> "Chili Pasilla" ist mein Lieblings-Chili. Wenn man es richtig sauber
>   entkernt ist es auch gar nicht scharf. Das scharfe an der Chili sind
>   die Kerne und die "Venen".

should become:

> „Chili Pasilla“ ist mein Lieblings-Chili. Wenn man es richtig sauber
>   entkernt ist es auch gar nicht scharf. Das scharfe an der Chili sind
>   die Kerne und die „Venen“.

Comment: I am not very firm with regular expressions, but I hope there is a way to solve it with them.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If you have, can you share it with us?

Comment: What do you mean by “everywhere automatically”? In a text file? In an application you don't have source for? In every piece of text ever written anywhere including the plaques on the moon?

Comment: Sorry, my question missed some details! I added my current approach. So, there are users writing texts in ASP.net web forms. I want to display these texts in a blog and replace the straight quotation marks every time a user saves the text.

Comment: Give us some sample text to work with, and provide how sample output should look like. There may be some edge cases for you to work out after that, but we could at least provide some approach to work with your sample data. Hopefully something more difficult than `"this"`

Comment: I suppose you could use this Regex `(")[^"]+"` and replace the first capture group with `„`, although it's not robust.

Comment: Regular expressions are used for parsing regular text - that's what the "regular" part means. Human languages are **not** regular. You are probably better off with the approach that you are currently using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if that's exactly what you are looking for, but here's the regex solution I would employ:

```
    public static string FixGermanQuotationMarks(string input)
    {
        var pattern = @"""([^""]*)""";
        return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, @"„$1“");
    }
```

It can be confusing with the quotes having to be escaped, so just imagine that the actual pattern would look more like this if it wasn't for escaping quotes: `"([^"]*)"`. Alright, let's break this down:

- `"` This matches your opening "regular" quote
- `(`       This is to capture the content that is surrounded by the quotes. If you don't know what that means, you'll see in a minute
- `[^"]` This matches everything that is not a quote (letters, numbers, whitespace, etc) The `^` is the negation operator when creating regexes, so `^"` means `*everything but*` **`"`**
- `*` This means that you can have zero or more of the previous item, which, in our case, was any character but the quote character. This is to make sure you capture as many letters as there are between the quotes.
- `)`We close our capture group
- `"` This matches the closing quote

Now, what did I mean by capture group ? It just means that, in the case of a match, we can actually reuse part of the match when the time comes to replace the content of the match in the original text. In our case, all we are interested about is the content that's between the two quotes, which is why we captured it. We can refer to what we have captured by using `$1`, which refers to the first (and in our case, the only) capture group. We then simply place this captured text between the German quotes, and use the resulting string to replace the whole match. As I mentionned before, it can be confusing when looking at the code I posted to see so many quotes, but a string literal has to be escaped using them.

After this, you only need to call the method like so:

```
var input = @"""Chili Pasilla"" ist mein Lieblings-Chili.";
var germanified = FixGermanQuotationMarks(input);
```

Hope this clarifies the regex method.

Comment: Very nice! It doesn't format a stray quote if there's one at the end, but that was not defined as a requirement. And it could also easily be added as an extension method if desired.

Comment: Actually, a rogue quote could have some disastrous results, depending on  its placement and if the output overwrites data. If we have something like: `"xxxxxxx"what_i_want_to_capture"xxxx`, the `x`'s will be captured, but the quoted content will not. In this case, if is probably safer to check if the quote count is at least before replacing.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Seems to work well with my real data. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

You could write an extension method on the string class to do it:

**EDIT** Based on good feedback, used a `StringBuilder` in extension method for better performance.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces every odd straight quote with '„' and every even straight quote with '“'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The string acting as the source for replacements.</param>
    /// <returns>A string with replacements made.</returns>
    public static string ReplaceStraightQuotes(this string source)
    {
        if (source == null) return null;

        var result = new StringBuilder(source);

        var lastIndex = source.IndexOf('"');
        int count = 0;

        while (lastIndex > -1)
        {
            char replaceQuote = (count++ % 2 == 0) ? '„' : '“';
            result.Replace('"', replaceQuote, lastIndex, 1);
            lastIndex = source.IndexOf('"', lastIndex + 1);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
var result = "He said, \"Hello, you look lovely.\"";
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(result.ReplaceStraightQuotes());
```

Output:

> result = "He said, \"Hello, you look lovely.\""
>
> result.ReplaceStraightQuotes() = 
>   "He said, „Hello, you look lovely.“"

Comment: Note that is code that deals with longer strings `StringBuilder` would be better (and you can just replace characters in-place that way).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good feedback, thanks. Incorporated it in my answer.